# find sup of the function

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n  a_ix_i  -  x_iln(x_i) $$

$a_i$ are given real nos
variables-
$x_i$ are all non-negative and $\sum_{i=1}^n = 1$

given is a function from $\mathcal R^n $ to $\mathcal R $
find its sup
(it is magically given that $x_iln(x_i)=0$ for $x_i=0 $ )

I am lost, I know concepts of sup and inf...this is a real analysis problem so please avoid using optimization techniques, I want to know the thought process and not just the solution like what made you think in a way that you did.

Comment: What sum is supposed to be $1$? Is it $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=1$? Or is it $\sum_{i=1}^na_i=1$? This makes a great difference.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you have defined
$$
f:\{x\in\mathbb R^n~:~x_i\geq 0\text{ for all }i=1,\ldots,n\}\to \mathbb R
$$
defined by
$$
f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i-x_i\ln(x_i).
$$
The assumption to say $x_i\ln(x_i)\mid_{x_i=0}=0$ is not magical because you can compute that there holds
$$
\lim_{t\to 0^+}t\cdot\ln(t)=0.
$$
Next, the function looks complicated, but it can be broken down to a simple situation. Let us define
$$
g_a:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R,~g_a(t)=\begin{cases}at-t\cdot\ln(t) & t>0\\0 & t=0\end{cases}.
$$
Then, we get $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n g_{a_i}(x_i)$.

If you can understand how to compute the supremum and infimum of $g_a$ for an $a\in\mathbb R$, then you can use that to find the supremum and infimum of $f$.

**Hints:**

> If $g_a(t)\to \infty$ then $g_a$ is unbounded from above and $\sup_{t\geq 0} g_a(t)=\infty$. Analogous for $g_a(t)\to-\infty$...

> Consider the critical points of $g_a$. They might be useful to find the supremum and infimum of $g_a$. But be aware of the sign of $a$!

> $$\sup_{x_1,x_2\geq 0}g_{a_1}(x_1)+g_{a_2}(x_2)=\sup_{x_1\geq 0}g_{a_1}(x_1)+\sup_{x_2\geq 0}g_{a_2}(x_2)$$